# Model to explain why the correlation is bad

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, lme4-nlme

I performed three experiments where I measured a metabolite in blood over time using two different methods (called `gs` and `se` in the following). One of these methods (`se`) relies on a sensor implanted in each individual. This sensor is probably subjected to some variations over time (but not over a peridod of time so short that it would affect the results within one experiment), while the other method is very stable and reliable. The correlation between the measurements with both methods is around 0.6 (and the relationship is not strictly linear -- as shown by a loess regression line).

I then plotted the values of one method against the other within each individual for each experiment and found that the relationship between them was linear in every case.

I simulated some data below to reproduce mine:

```
set.seed(1)
rands <- rep(rnorm(18, 1, 0.5), each = 6) # different slope for each combination of ind and exp
exp <- factor(rep(1:3, 6, each = 6))
ind <- factor(rep(1:6, each = 18))
gs <- rep(1:6, 18) + rnorm(108)
se <- gs * rands + rnorm(108)
df <- data.frame(ind, exp, gs, se)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(gs, se, group = exp, color = exp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ ind, labeller = label_both)
```

[image: corresponding plot]

Obviously, as these GAM regression lines are linear they can be reproduced using the following linear model: `lm(se ~ gs * exp * ind, df)`. **What I want to show is that even if the correlation *per se* is quite bad, the relationship between the values is linear within one experiment so that this sensor can be used for monitoring over periods of time corresponding to the experiments while it cannot be used to get reliable absolute values.**

Therefore I would compare this model to the model corresponding to a simple correlation (`lm(se ~ gs, df)`). As of course, the fit of the model will increase by adding predictors, I used AIC and BIC. I have some hypotheses on why I have different slopes between and within individuals, but I am still worried by the questions:

1. is it a valid approach to say that as the AIC is lower with the full model, parts of the variability responsible for the low correlation can be explained by `ind` and `exp`?
2. is it acceptable not to use a mixed model here, despite looking at differences within individuals?

Regarding my second question, I tried but I did not succeed since the slopes obtained do not fit so well and the AIC is not as low as without a random term. My best guess until now was:

```
m1 <- lm(se ~ gs, df)
m2 <- lm(se ~ gs * exp * ind, df)
library(lme4)
m3 <- lmer(se ~ (1 + gs | exp / ind), df, REML = F) # REML = F to compare to lm
AIC(m1, m2, m3)
#    df      AIC 
# m1  3 462.9444 
# m2 37 360.7580
# m3  8 395.5307
```

So this adds further questions:

3. Is my model with random slope and intercept correctly specified?
4. Should I keep this model despite higher AIC (compared to `m2`)?

Thank you for your advice!